# How to convert country names to ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 values in arm template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, country-codes, iso-3166

I have an ARM-template and I would like convert country name like "United States" and I would like to get the ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 code like "US". This converted value I would use for name of resource group. I tryed use condicion "if", but this options i can use in case when Parametr "CountryString" contains only two country. I am not able to find solutions for parameter "CountryObject" which contains more than two country. Is there a way to do this?

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
"parameters": {
        "CountryString": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": { "Description": "Select a country from the list." },
        "defaultValue": "United States",
        "allowedValues": [ "United States", "Germany"]
    },
    "CountryObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "defaultValue": {
            "United States": "US",
            "Germany": "DE",
            "United Kingdom": "GB"
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
     "OutputString": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[if(equals('United States', parameters('CountryString')), 'US','DE')]"
    },
      "Outputobject": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[if(equals('United States', parameters('CountryObject')), 'US','DE')]"
    },
     "rgName": "[concat('rg-',variables('Outputobject').value, '-rgname')]"
},

   "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
        "location": "East Asia",
        "name": "[variables('rgName')]",
        "properties": {}
    }],
"outputs": {
    "OutputString": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('OutputString').value]"
    },
        "Outputobject": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('Outputobject').value]"
    }
}}
```

[Deploy to azure](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FCmajda%2FArm-Template%2Fmain%2Fdraft%2Frg_iso_a2_country.json)

[Template here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cmajda/Arm-Template/main/draft/rg_iso_a2_country.json)

Comment: That is an elegant solution. Thank you mr Stringfellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `if` statement, treat the `CountryObject` like a hashtable.

```
      "value": "[parameters('CountryObject')[parameters('CountryString')]]"
```

The whole thing.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
  "parameters": {
    "CountryString": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": { "Description": "Select a country from the list." },
      "defaultValue": "United States",
      "allowedValues": [ "United States", "Germany" ]
    },
    "CountryObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {
        "United States": "US",
        "Germany": "DE",
        "United Kingdom": "GB"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "OutputString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('CountryObject')[parameters('CountryString')]]"
    }  },

  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "OutputString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('OutputString').value]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final solution that I used:
**Parameters** "CountryObject" replaced to **Variable** "CountryObject"

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
"parameters": {
    "CountryString": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": { "Description": "Select a country from the list." },
        "allowedValues": [
            "United States",
            "Germany",
            "United Kingdom"
        ]
    }
},
"variables": {
    "CountryObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": {
            "United States": "US",
            "Germany": "DE",
            "United Kingdom": "GB"

        }
    },
    "OutputString": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[variables('CountryObject').value[parameters('CountryString')]]"
    }
},

"resources": [],
"outputs": {
    "OutputString": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('OutputString').value]"
    }
}}
```

[Template with a complete list of countries.](https://github.com/Cmajda/Arm-Template/blob/main/Samples/convert_country_to_isoA2.json)