# ARM Template globalization

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I Have two ARM templates to deploy resources in DEV and QA separately. Now my requirement is to create only one template to deploy resources in DEV and QA based on selected environment.

Someone help me how to create ARM template to deploy resources based on select Environment like DEV or QA.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried working with passing in a parameter to indicate the environment type and then using an variable object to lookup name patterns based on the environment parameter. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349356/how-to-convert-country-names-to-iso-3166-1-alpha-2-values-in-arm-template/64358434#64358434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, you could use [Logical functions for ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical?tabs=json) to create Azure resources with conditional action. Use the condition element to specify whether the resource is deployed. The value for this element resolves to true or false. When the value is true, the resource is created. When the value is false, the resource isn't created. The value can only be applied to the whole resource.

For more information, read the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-conditions): Use condition in ARM templates and [this](http://Conditional%20deployment%20in%20ARM%20templates).

Comment: Yes, i works with logical functions. can you help me with which functions should use to achieve above scenarios.

Comment: You can create each resource with `"condition": "[equals(parameters('production'), 'Yes')]",` when the condition expression is true, the resource will be provisioned, otherwise, if it's false, it does not. Or you can declare the reference to attributes based on the condition, For example, `"properties": {
                "availabilitySet": "[if(equals(parameters('production'), 'Yes'), variables('availabilitySetId'), json('null'))]",` , Read [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/create-flexible-arm-templates-using-conditions-and-logical-functions/) for more details.